# Array to csv download in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, csv, download

I am trying to turn my array in PHP into a csv to download.

Currently the array looks something like this

```
Array[0] = "Name,age,ID"
Array[1] = "Alex,26,1"
Array[2] = "Ryan,12,2"
Array[3] = "Steph,56,7"
```

etc

I was unsure how to make this download as a csv, where each array position is its own line is csv obviously.

I set the headers to the following :

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
```

then I tried to echo each element of the array, hoping this would work. as follows:

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
foreach ($lines as &$line) {
   echo $line;
}
```

Where `$lines` was my array.

However it did all one line in the csv. Is there a way I can turn this array to print properly in csv?

Comment: @PatrickQ done, was just a basic echo, didn't think it was needed.

Comment: `echo "$line\n";`

Comment: `echo` doesn't automatically add newlines at the end of your content. You have to do that explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add a newline

```
echo $line . "\n";
```

Even better

```
echo $line . PHP_EOL; //constant for correct line-ending depending on OS.
```

Comment: Use `PHP_EOL` for cross-platform newline: `echo $line, PHP_EOL;`

Comment: dear god I'm dumb. Think after coding in PHP for almost 2 years I would have caught that. I'll accept the answer when it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

One of solution is `fputcsv` function.

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $row = explode(',', $line);
    fputcsv($output, $row);
}
fclose($output);
```